# Hand contour not precise

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, contour

I wrote an OpenCV program to extract the hand out of the image precisely. But is not able to get it out correctly. Below is the code and the output and the sample image which I used to test it.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
  
# Reading image
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX
img2 = cv2.imread('1.bmp', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
  
# Reading same image in another 
# variable and converting to gray scale.
img = cv2.imread('1.bmp', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
  
# Converting image to a binary image
# ( black and white only image).
_, threshold = cv2.threshold(img, 110, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
  
# Detecting contours in image.
contours, _= cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_TREE,
                               cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours1 = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)  
# Going through every contours found in the image.
  
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contours1, 0.009 * cv2.arcLength(contours1, True), True)

# draws boundary of contours.
cv2.drawContours(img2, [approx], 0, (0, 0, 255), 5) 

cv2.imshow('image2', img2) 
  
# Exiting the window if 'q' is pressed on the keyboard.
if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('q'): 
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Input image -

[image: Input Image]

[image: Output Image]

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the epsilon parameter to `approxPolyDP`?

Comment: no but does that help! i dont know

Comment: that wasn't a question Tom asked, that was a recommendation. he *knows* it is the problem (it *is* the problem), he's just being polite. and you should _try_ to follow his suggestion before saying that you "don't know" -- taking the contour's perimeter is usually a good idea but for hand contours you see they've got a lot more perimeter in relation to their area, so the factor in the epsilon needs to be smaller than usual.

Comment: Yes i tried out with different values of epsilon and it didn't work well on certain images

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons your contour is not precise is the obvious; the line where you approximated the contour. But you have also mentioned (in a comment) that lowering the approximation didn't solve the problem.

This is because you didn't blur the thresholded image, which resulted in the jagged edges. Here is an example where the thresholded image is blurred before the contour detection:

The code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def process(img):
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    return cv2.threshold(img_gray, 111, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

def draw_contours(img):
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(process(img), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    cnt = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
    cv2.drawContours(img, [cnt], -1, (0, 0, 255), 2)

img = cv2.imread("image.png")
draw_contours(img)
cv2.imshow("result", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Input image:

[image]

Output image:

[image]

Still, the contour isn't very precise. This is where the Canny edge detector comes into play:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def process(img):
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    _, thresh = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 111, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(thresh, (5, 5), 4)
    img_canny = cv2.Canny(img_blur, 0, 0)
    img_dilate = cv2.dilate(img_canny, None, iterations=1)
    return cv2.erode(img_dilate, None, iterations=0)

def draw_contours(img):
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(process(img), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    cnt = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
    cv2.drawContours(img, [cnt], -1, (0, 0, 255), 2)

img = cv2.imread("image.png")
draw_contours(img)
cv2.imshow("result", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]